# Forcing central alignment in table

Tags: tables

I am having a table and I want the references aligned in a beautiful way (centralized). The last entry needs a * and kills my beautiful alignment - what is the best way to have them aligned es if the * would not be there?

[image: Screenshot of table]

Comment: as you have shown no code hard to tell you how to change your code but `\rlap{*}` takes up no space.  (I would left align the second column, the centred text is a bit distracting)

Comment: you are the best - saved my evening. Thanks a lot that works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\rlap{*}` takes up no space....